# jquery shorthand for find() statement

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, shorthand

I have a super simple question, instead of doing something like this:

```
$(".one").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.two').find('.three').css...
});
```

with this HTML:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

is there a short hand where you can skip the word find in some way?

Comment: do mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/j9Tyf/ ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('#one #two #three')
```

**But remember that `ID` in a page is supposed to be unique**

So `$('#three').css()` should be sufficient

It makes sense when the elements are either `class` elements or `tagNames`

```
$('.one .two .three') <--
$('div span p')       <--  These are fine
```

All these should work

```
// Using find to target the class
$(this).find('.two').find('.three').css('border', '1px dashed red');
// Using find to target the class
$(this).find('.two .three').css('border', '1px dashed red');
// Using the this context
$('.two .three',this).css('border', '1px dashed red');
// Using the this context and immediate children
$('> .two > .three',this).css('border', '1px dashed red');
```

`>` will only get the immediate children . The other 2 are using `this` as a context

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gjc8c/1/)**

Comment: so if I had the HTML like I updated it, would this still work?

Comment: can you check the update one more time, sorry I'm doing a bad job explaining, still work with that?

Comment: I made [a fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/xBDJQ/) at the same time Sush did...

Comment: `$(this).find('.two').find('.three')` can actually just be `$(this).find('.two .three')`

Comment: thanks for being patient while I worked my thought process out :)  I appreciate it!

Comment: @loriensleafs.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the selector context http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

```
$(".one").on('click', function() {
    $('.three', this).css...
});
```

Its the simplest way to go about it.

---

also

```
$(".one").click(function() {
    $(this).find('.three').css...
});
```

would work fine, you don't have to traverse every step.